# Cloudflare + Reverse Proxy - Error 1000

Tags: node.js, wordpress, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

because of SEO I have setup a reverse proxy that works fine:

The setup is as follows:

**1)** http://www.example.com (node.js hosted at heroku)

**2)** http://blog.example.com (wordpress hosted at godaddy)

**3)** visitors accessing http://www.example.com/blog get content from http://blog.example.com.

This works fine and at 1) I also have the proxy working with the popular nodejitsu htt-proxy and httpProxyRules modules:

```
// Set up proxy rules instance 
var proxyRules = new httpProxyRules({
    rules: {
      '.*/blog': 'https://blog.example.com', // Rule (1) 
    },
    default: 'https://www.example.com' // default target 
});

// Create reverse proxy instance 
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxy();

// Create http server that leverages reverse proxy instance 
// and proxy rules to proxy requests to different targets 
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // a match method is exposed on the proxy rules instance 
    // to test a request to see if it matches against one of the specified rules 
    var target = proxyRules.match(req);
    if (target) {
      return proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: target,
        changeOrigin: true,
      });
    }

    res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('The request url and path did not match any of the listed rules!');

}).listen(6010);
```

Then I tried adding Cloudflare SSL certificates so I could have https. I know that Cloudflare acts as a reverse-proxy itself. So in total I would have 3 reverse-proxies in my setup, 1), 2) (both with Cloudflare's reverse-proxy) and 3) (my custom reverse-proxy).

Separately, both 1) and 2) worked fine with https. However, 3) broke.

For 3), I keep getting the error:

**Error 1000 - DNS points to prohibited IP**

What is going on and how should I proceed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

So, you are pointing your CloudFlare DNS to another proxy in your zone file. Because CloudFlare is also a reverse proxy, [enabling a proxy on a record may create a cyclic loop](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203487280--How-do-I-fix-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-after-enabling-Flexible-SSL-with-WordPress-).

In order to resolve this, your Node.js proxy should ideally point straight to the origin web server and not go back through CloudFlare. If you don't want to update your script, on the server you might be able to add direct routes to your origins by updating the hosts file on the web server doing the proxying.

Comment: Hi mjsa, about "your Node.js proxy should ideally point straight to the origin web server and not go back through CloudFlare." Could you be more specific about how should I do that by changing the node.js reverse-proxy script?

Comment: Go ahead and change the /etc/hosts file on the server hosting the script such that those domains point straight to the origin server. Else you could use IP addresses to the origin server instead of the domain name in your script.